# Python 3 | Send email -- SMTP -- gmail -- Error : SMTPException

Tags: email, python-3.x, smtp-auth

I want to send an email by use of Python 3. I cannot yet make sense of the examples that I have seen. Here is one reference: [Using Python to Send Email](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/using-python-to-send-email/)

I have pulled the first simple example found on the above reference. I find this example a good representation of the combination of examples I have seen on the internet. It seems to be the basic form of doing what I am trying to do.

When I try the code below, I receive Error:

```
File "C:\Python33\Lib\email.py", line 595, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Here is the code:

```
# Send Mail

import smtplib
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# Log in to the server
server.login("myEmail@gmail.com","myPassword")

# Send mail
msg = "\nHello!"
server.sendmail("myEmail@gmail.com","recipient@gmail.com", msg)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found a solution on YouTube.

Here is the [video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3RH7vi7j7M).

```
# smtplib module send mail

import smtplib

TO = 'recipient@mailservice.com'
SUBJECT = 'TEST MAIL'
TEXT = 'Here is a message from python.'

# Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = 'password'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO,
                    'From: %s' % gmail_sender,
                    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,
                    '', TEXT])

try:
    server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
    print ('email sent')
except:
    print ('error sending mail')

server.quit()
```

Answer (score 6):

As of mid-October 2017, gmail isn't accepting connections via `smtplib.SMTP()` on port `587`, but requires `smtplib.SMTP_SSL()` and port `465`.  This starts `TLS` immediately, and `ehlo` isn't needed.  Try this snippet instead:

```
# Gmail Sign In
gmail_sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = 'password'

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

# build and send the email body.
```

Comment: Just tried it.. I am wondering that I can use this one locally but not from my server as google still says `Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754`

Comment: You seem to be wrong. Gmail today as of Mar 28, 2020 is seemingly accepting on port 587. However you need to enable this gmail account as "insecure" one, and this is considered as a vulnerability by Gmail security monitoring. But you can still send this "insecure" way, and it in fact works in my system, messages do get sent and do arrive to target mailboxes; all via the port 587.

Comment: @gies0r you need to disable the two-factor auth in your gmail account settings for this to work ok.

Comment: But I send to `587` with Java SSL, and all seems to be okay. Python v.3.6.9 reports 'ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number' when trying to login with `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` on port `587`. Java Oracle JDK does't report this.

Comment: @gies0r When one logs in with SSL on port `465` from a *new* IP address which is unknown to Gmail, one gets `smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <...\n5.7.14 ...\n5.7.14 ...>\n5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 ... - gsmtp')`. You need go to gmail account settings and confirm this IP address is secure, after this you can login and send okay with Python API.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I sent an email using Google. Capital letters represent personal information that needs to be edited

```
try:
    import RUNNING_SCRIPT
except:
    print("threw exception")
    # smtplib module send mail

    import smtplib

    TO = ‘EXAMPLE_RECIPIENT@gmail.com'
    SUBJECT = 'SERVER DOWN'
    TEXT = 'Here is a message from python. Your server is down, please check.'

    # Gmail Sign In
    gmail_sender = ‘YOUR_GMAIL_ACCOUNT@gmail.com'
    gmail_passwd = ‘APPLICATION SPECIFIC PASSWORD’

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

    BODY = '\r\n'.join(['To: %s' % TO, 'From: %s' % gmail_sender,'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,'', TEXT])

    try:
        server.sendmail(gmail_sender, [TO], BODY)
        print ('email sent')
    except:
        print ('error sending mail')
        server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This function is working for me:

```
`def server_connect(account, password, server, port=587):
    if int(port) == 465:    # gmail server
        email_server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server, str(port))
    else:
        email_server = smtplib.SMTP(server, port)
        email_server.ehlo()
        email_server.starttls()
    email_server.login(account, password)
    return email_server
#--------
`
```

I hope this helps.