# Python smtp send email from gmail ,

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

[image]I use python to send email from gmail.I turn gmail IMAP on also get a security password(a 16 bit password).But reply me UserName and Password not accepted.I u se the google account password,port 25,587,465(use ssl).can not work.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email import encoders

import smtplib
sender = "Mygmail@gmail.com"
rec= "reciver@qq.com"
passwd = "security password"
#passwd = 'the really google account password'

message = MIMEText("邮件发送","plain","utf-8")
message['From'] =sender
message['To'] = rec
message['Subject'] =Header("from google","utf-8").encode()

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
smtpObj.ehlo()                 
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.set_debuglevel(1)
smtpObj.login(sender,passwd)
smtpObj.sendmail(sender,[rec],message.as_string)
smtpObj.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, it has worked for me in the past

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#from smtplib import SMTP # Standard connection
from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP #SSL connection
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

sender = 'example@gmail.com'
receivers = ['example@gmail.com']


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'example@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'example@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'simple email via python test 1'
message = 'This is the body of the email line 1\nLine 2\nEnd'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

ServerConnect = False
try:
    smtp_server = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com','465')
    smtp_server.login('#name#@gmail.com', '#password#')
    ServerConnect = True
except SMTPHeloError as e:
    print "Server did not reply"
except SMTPAuthenticationError as e:
    print "Incorrect username/password combination"
except SMTPException as e:
    print "Authentication failed"

if ServerConnect == True:
    try:
        smtp_server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
        print "Successfully sent email"
    except SMTPException as e:
        print "Error: unable to send email", e
    finally:
        smtp_server.close()
```

Comment: which password should I use ,google account password or security password?

Comment: This code makes no attempt to use any password other than the gmail password

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332384/python-3-send-email-smtp-gmail-error-smtpexception/46754666#46754666